# Как сделать что бы QTextEdit Была по размеру окна PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtextedit, qlayout

Дизайнером не пользуюсь, пишу код сам. Так вот: Надо, что бы `QTextEdit` был по размеру окна и не закрывал ни `statusbar`, ни `menubar`. Когда меняешь размер окна, `QTextEdit` меняет размер тоже.

Если, я просто установлю размер и передвину `QTextEdit`, куда надо, то при изменении размера окна `QTextEdit` не изменится.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import(QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main()

    def main(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PlainNote")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("img/ico.png"))

        self.resize(560, 315)
        self.move(300, 300)

        exitAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Exit", self)
        exitAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exitAction.setStatusTip("Close the app")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)

        newFileAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&New file", self)
        newFileAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        newFileAction.setStatusTip("Create new file")
#        newFileAction.triggered.connect()

        saveAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Save", self)
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        saveAction.setStatusTip("Save file")
#        saveAction.triggered.connect()

        saveAsAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Save as...", self)
        saveAsAction.setStatusTip("Save file as...")
#        saveAsAction.triggered.connect()

        openAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Open...", self)
        openAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        openAction.setStatusTip("Open file...")
#        openAction.triggered.connect()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(newFileAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAsAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.textBlock = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.textBlock.setWordWrapMode(False)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("...")

def start():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите `self.textBlock`  как `self.setCentralWidget(self.textBlock)`

Подробнее читаем здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import(QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main()

    def main(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PlainNote")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("img/ico.png"))

        self.resize(560, 315)
#        self.move(300, 300)

        exitAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Exit", self)
        exitAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exitAction.setStatusTip("Close the app")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)

        newFileAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&New file", self)
        newFileAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        newFileAction.setStatusTip("Create new file")
#        newFileAction.triggered.connect()

        saveAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Save", self)
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        saveAction.setStatusTip("Save file")
#        saveAction.triggered.connect()

        saveAsAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Save as...", self)
        saveAsAction.setStatusTip("Save file as...")
#        saveAsAction.triggered.connect()

        openAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Open...", self)
        openAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        openAction.setStatusTip("Open file...")
#        openAction.triggered.connect()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(newFileAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAsAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.textBlock = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.textBlock.setWordWrapMode(False)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("...")
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textBlock)             # +++

def start():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]